# Why the button.selected always nil in iOS?

Tags: ios, button, null

```
cell1.withMedicalServicePriceBtn.selected = NO;
```

I would entrust value in everyWhere,but...

like this :

```
po cell1.withMedicalServicePriceBtn.selected
<nil>
```

is nil

First time use stack overflow ,don't use picture ,please help me ,Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`po command(print object)` for printing objects. No matter its bool or not. So if you want to print bool please use `p command(print)`. Your code is ok and `selected == NO`

Answer (score 0):

Just consider the property `selected` is NO if `cell1` and `withMedicalServicePriceBtn` are both not nil.

Because `po` command considers 0 as NO as nil sometimes.

Comment: Yes, it's not nil , but the selected always nil